# In Google Colab, can you add a Markdown setting which will be applied automatically?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I write most of my text in Hebrew, or a mix of Hebrew / English. for this, I need to add the following line to each text block:

div dir="rtl" lang="he" xml:lang="he">
(this didn't paste very well...)

but it's annoying to paste this each time. Is there a way to have this auto-pasted? better yet, is there a method to configure colab to work right to left by default?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not exactly what you are looking for, but here is tip that may help. You can create a code snippet with the line that you want to insert to more easily add it to your notebooks.

- I create a small notebook with your snippet here https://gist.github.com/alexheat/b1bf37371a2d132cbd5b562e89d008d5.
- In Google Colab settings, there is a section that says "Custom notebook snippet URL' enter this URL https://colab.research.google.com/gist/alexheat/b1bf37371a2d132cbd5b562e89d008d5/ltr.ipynb
- Now create a new notebook and insert a snippet. You can type "Hebrew" to find the snippet. Insert the snippet.
- This will create a code cell. To convert it to a markdown cell type Command+M+M.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot alexheat!

this still requires quite a few clicks before actually writing some Hebrew text, but it's still better than what I currently do.

if you ever come across something fully automatic, please share -)

Gideon